# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, nullpointerexception

I have a bug in my app and I don't know how to resolve it. When I try to run my app, it just says, unfortunately app has stopped and in the logcat it says this:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference' on a null object reference

t is suppose to take the user to the login activity since the user is not logged in. This is the code of the fragment where the error is being pointed to.

```
package com.app.whatsupafrica;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;


/**
* A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
*/
public class ChatsFragment extends Fragment
{
private View PrivateChatsView;
private RecyclerView chatsList;

private DatabaseReference ChatsRef, UsersRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String currentUserID;


public ChatsFragment()
{
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    PrivateChatsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUserID = mAuth.getUid();
    if (mAuth.getUid() == null)
    {
     SendUserToLoginActivity();
    }
    if (! mAuth.getUid().isEmpty())
    {
        ChatsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contacts").child(mAuth.getUid());
    }
    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


    chatsList = (RecyclerView) PrivateChatsView.findViewById(R.id.chats_list);
    chatsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


    return PrivateChatsView;
}


@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();


    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>()
            .setQuery(ChatsRef, Contacts.class)
            .build();


    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, ChatsViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, ChatsViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ChatsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Contacts model)
                {
                    final String usersIDs = getRef(position).getKey();
                    final String[] retImage = {"default_image"};

                    UsersRef.child(usersIDs).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                        {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                            {
                                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image"))
                                {
                                    retImage[0] = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                                    Picasso.get().load(retImage[0]).into(holder.profileImage);
                                }

                                final String retName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                                final String retStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

                                holder.userName.setText(retName);
                                // holder.userStatus.setText("Last Seen: " + "\n" + "Date " + " Time");

                                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v)
                                    {
                                        Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                                        chatIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", usersIDs);
                                        chatIntent.putExtra("visit_user_name", retName);
                                        chatIntent.putExtra("visit_image", retImage[0]);
                                        startActivity(chatIntent);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public ChatsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
                {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_display_layout, viewGroup, false);
                    return new ChatsViewHolder(view);
                }
            };

    chatsList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}




public static class ChatsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    CircleImageView profileImage;
    TextView userStatus, userName;


    public ChatsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

        profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);
        userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_status);
        userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
    }
}
private void SendUserToLoginActivity()
{
    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(loginIntent);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to place a breakpoint and inspect the reason why it is happening?

Comment: Maybe you should be checking mAuth.getCurrentUser(). If the user is logged out, the user is null and you can't call getUid() on something that is null. Have you tried checking this?

Comment: @Norik i will try that now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user has signed in or not

```
 if(! Objects.requireNonNull( mAuth.getUid() ).isEmpty())
     currentUserID = mAuth.getUid();
 else
     //sign in the user
```

Comment: I just tried that. It did not still fix it. Do you know any other thing i can do?

Comment: Are you sure that the user is logged in?

Comment: No, the user is not logged in. Thats why i did this                                                                                if(! Objects.requireNonNull( mAuth.getUid() ).isEmpty())
     currentUserID = mAuth.getUid();
 else
     Intent loginIntent = new Intent(getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(loginIntent);

Comment: Can you copy-paste the logcat text or image?

Comment: this is it.......      Process: com.app.whatsupafrica, PID: 29208
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

Comment: It is because of this line      ChatsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contacts").child(currentUserID);   since currentUserID is null

Comment: So, what do you think i should do

Comment: Get that reference line inside an if-else statement, if( ! currentUserID.isEmpty) ChatsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contacts").child(currentUserID);

Comment: Thank you, i will try that now

Comment: I just did that, but it did not work. This is the new error in the logcat                                    "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference"

Comment: Its better to use (! mAuth.getUid().isEmpty()) instread of  (! currentUserID.isEmpty)

Comment: i jaust changed that again and it still gives the same error, which is                                                     "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference"

Comment: Please what do i do

Comment: Can you update your question by copy-pasting all the changes u made in the code ?

Comment: okay, i will do that now

Comment: i have done that.... please take a look at the code and tell me if there is anything i should do

Comment: Replace currentUserId in the if-else statement to mAuth.getUid(). becasue if user isnt logged in then currentUserId will result in NullPointerException

Comment: I have done it.... It is still the same thing

Comment: please i really need helpurgently

Comment: Can u update the code again?

Comment: i have updated the code again

Comment: Replace ( == null ) with isEmpty()

Answer (score 0):

Add this code:

```
mAuth.getUid();
```

instead of

```
mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Apparently current user is null

Comment: i just tried that, it still says app has stopped. But it brought out a different error. This time it brought out, "java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()"

Comment: Is the problem solved?